# Purge old messages activemq

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I'm trying to find a way to purge a few messages based on their timestamp. is there a way I can do that by doing any setting in broker config in activemq.

I need to do this because I'm using the queues to recieve and the configured db to store messages for later consumption. But after a certain (a large) number of messages in pending (stored) state I'm not able to dequeue new messages though they have different metadata.

Thank you for any suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

> Message Producer expiration...

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-set-the-message-expiration.html

Comment: Thank you. But this is a solution from the producer side. also, the existing messages in store do not have expiration set. Is there a way we can purge the existing messages based on when they were created?

Comment: If you can't control setting expiration from the producer, then you'll need to create a consumer that checks creation time against some predefined expiration; if true, just consume the message (that will remove it from the queue). Why can't you control setting the expiration from the producer?

Comment: I can control the new messages from the producers side, but there are around 10000 messages already in pending state and some of them I need to get rid of based on timestamp. I was hoping to have something like this available from Activemq webconsole.